# How to use `Action` with Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use `Times` function in a Unity, by following [this site](http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/rubys-times-function-in-csharp/) I use this script.

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static void Times(this int i, Action<int> func)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            func(j);
        }
    }
}
```

But it causes error:

> Assets/Resources/Scripts/Board.cs(27,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Action 1` could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

It looks like there is no `Action` in Unity C#.

Is there way to use the function in Unity?
And where should I put the file if I want to use throughout my Unity project?

Comment: Are you using C# or Unity Script? Those are two different languages you can use to target the Unity 3d engine. Your snippet, and the web site you link to, are C#.

Comment: I'm using C#. It was a mistake that I wrote `Unity Script` in my question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `Action<T>` delegate type is defined in the `System` namespace - make sure you have `using System;` as a directive at the top of your CS file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use only once then you can also use like `System.Action<int>` function. But If you are using more than once in script then you should use `Using System`.